# Есть ли функция для извлечения текста из сообщения и сохранения ее как переменной?

Tags: python, telebot, бот

Всем привет, вопрос немного странный, но не могу извлечь из сообщения пользователя название города, для прогноза погоды - одной из функций бота.
Прошу, подскажите как передать боту информацию из сообщения

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):

 chat_id = message.chat.id
 ms_text = message.text

 cur_user = Users.getUser(chat_id)
 if cur_user == None:
     cur_user = Users(chat_id, message.json["from"])

 result = goto_menu(chat_id, ms_text)  # попытаемся использовать текст как команду меню, и войти в него
 if result == True:
     return  # мы вошли в подменю, и дальнейшая обработка не требуется

 cur_menu = Menu.getCurMenu(chat_id)
 if cur_menu != None and ms_text in cur_menu.buttons:  # проверим, что команда относится к текущему меню

     if ms_text == "Помощь":
         send_help(chat_id)
elif ms_text == "Прогноз погоды":

             try:



                 r = lambda message: requests.get(
                     f'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={ms_text}&appid={OWM}&units=metric'
                 )
                 my_input(bot, chat_id, "Как тебя зовут?", r)
                 data = r.json()
                 #pprint(data)

                 city = data['name']
                 cur_weather = data['main']['temp']
                 humidity = data['main']['humidity']
                 pressure = data['main']['pressure']
                 wind = data['wind']['speed']

                 bot.send_message(chat_id, text=f'погода в городе: {city} \nТемпература: {cur_weather}С\n'
                        f'Влажность: {humidity}%\nДавление: {pressure} мм.рт.ст\nВетер: {wind}м/с\n')



             except Exception as e:
                 bot.send_message(chat_id, text=e)
                 bot.send_message(chat_id, text=r)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С лямбдой Вы перемудрили. Вот здесь `data = r.json()`, `r` это функция, для того чтобы получить результат ее работы ее нужно вызвать `r()` а Вы этого не делаете

Comment: @Namerek без нее он тоже не вставляет наименование города в api-ссылку. не понимаю как ему указать на это

Comment: Вангую, что вместо вашей лямбды должно находиться что-то такое: `r = requests.get(f'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={<city_name>}&appid={OWM}&units=metric')`, Просто `q="Прогноз погоды"` как-то нелепо выглядит. Согласитесь

Comment: @Namerek Соглашусь с вами, однако он просто не дает возможности ввести название.... сразу принимает за название "name" ,а если удалять "name" то принимает за название "main". Я не понимаю с чем это связано.........

Comment: Скажите, а код, который в вопросе, у Вас там где Вы его запускать пытаетесь, так-же выглядит? (в смысле форматирования)